# Why wasn't Cage strapped in for the final raid?

Tags: plot-explanation, edge-of-tomorrow

At end of Edge of Tomorrow, when Cage and Rita and the crew are flying to the Louvre, the crew starts jumping out of the transport. Rita looks at Cage with a surprised look and says something like "you're not strapped in." Then she jumps out and he goes down with the ship.

What was going on in that moment? Was Cage tricking her somehow? I feel like there was some sort of twist occurring right then, but I missed the full context.

Comment: The first time they land on the beach one can see that the soldiers don't actually _jump_ out of the plane, but they _drop_, while attached to a cable (to break their fall). - What Rita says is: _"You are not hooked in."_, meaning that Cage was not attached to a cable (which is why he doesn't "drop" like others, but crash lands in the water with the plane).

Comment: Yes, I understand that. What I don't understand is Cage's plan. Why wasn't he hooked in? Why didn't he tell Rita in advance?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have just rewatched the scene and it doesn't look like it's a part of some elaborate plan.

Seconds before the conversation from the OP's question takes place, Cage seems to hook himself as well (as the others do the same). However, the first hit at the ship blows him out of his strap (and kills Kimmel). Here, I made a clip of that part:

[Edge of Tomorrow: The beginning of the final attack](https://web.archive.org/web/20230505103343/https://i.imgur.com/Mtw71MV.mp4)

When they start jumping out, Rita tells him that he's not hooked in, which is the synonym for "but you cannot jump (and will crash with the plane)". Remember that not more than a minute before that, he said "take one for the team" (as a response to "what do we do if an alpha tries to kill us?"), so his reaction to Rita's comment (shaking his head and pressing her "release" button) is exactly that: accepting his own sacrifice for the team.

Of course, he's Tom Cruise, so he luckily survives the fall and (spoiler! ;-)) saves the day, but at that moment with Rita, Cage knows his chances are slim, and he just wants everyone else to go on and win the war.

Comment: +1 and accept, thanks very much! Video was bonus. And Cruise character being willing to sacrifice himself makes perfect sense given movie's theme of Cruise character maturing.

Comment: Thank you. And yes, him being willing to sacrifice himself for the final goal is sort of an end of that maturing process, because he knows (or, maybe better, believes) that if he dies this time, he will not wake up again, yet there is not a tiny trace of that perky Cage that tried to cheerfully talk his way out of the final battle.

Comment: About the linked video, I've reuploaded to another host as per [Links to tinypic.com are about to become permanently broken on August 26, 2019](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332659/162827)

Comment: @galacticninja, I didn't know that. Thank you for fixing the problem!

Comment: @VedranŠego FYI: Streamable, the site hosting the video here which I've re-uploaded back in Aug. 2019, has emailed me stating that the video will be deleted in 30 days due to inactivity.

Comment: @galacticninja, that's not nice of them. I've reuploaded to Imgur. They seem to be nice with old content. Thank you for the notification.

Comment: Please note, on May 15, 2023, [Imgur will be removing content that is not tied to a user account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388556/162827). This may affect this video you included in your post if it was uploaded to Imgur while not logged in to an account on Imgur. If this is the case, I recommend that you edit your post and reupload the media while logged in to an account on Imgur.

Comment: @galacticninja, thank you. I tried to re-upload it, but it keeps failing and I have no idea why. If you have any other suggestions (that don't involve me opening accounts on some social media platform), I can try that too.

Comment: @VedranŠego I've [archived the video to web.archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20230505103343/https://i.imgur.com/Mtw71MV.mp4), so there will be a backup copy even if it gets deleted by Imgur. I also tried uploading it to Imgur, but the upload doesn't have audio.

Comment: @galacticninja, thank you. I've edited the answer.